# Add column to end of the file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, debian

This is very basic question and I have done this more 100 times in the past but somehow it is not working this time.

I used the sed command to add the column at the end of the file but it is adding beginning of the file.

Version:
**uname -a**

```
Linux instance-2 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**cat temp**

```
25180,D22 Building Materials,USD,Cuba,0tm59h1qf0,2013-03-04,2017-08-11 10:09:37
```

Sed Command:

**sed 's/$/,dfd/g' temp**

```
,dfd0,D22 Building Materials,USD,Cuba,0tm59h1qf0,2013-03-04,2017-08-11 10:09:37
```

Output of "od -c":

```
cat temp | od -c
0000000 357 273 277   2   5   1   8   0   ,   D   2   2       B   u   i
0000020   l   d   i   n   g       M   a   t   e   r   i   a   l   s   ,
0000040   U   S   D   ,   C   u   b   a   ,   0   t   m   5   9   h   1
0000060   q   f   0   ,   2   0   1   3   -   0   3   -   0   4   ,   2
0000100   0   1   7   -   0   8   -   1   1       1   0   :   0   9   :
0000120   3   7  \r  \n
0000124
```

Please help me.

Comment: https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF9FXyclLUU//f9/I1NDCwMdFyMjBafSzJyUzLx0Bd/EktSizMScYp3QYBcd59KkRB2DklxTywzDwjQDHSMDQ2NdAyAyATHNdQ0sdA0NFQwNAA

Comment: Don't know why in your machine, it is different output. I tested on my terminal and also in web that I provided above the link. In the it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has `\r\n` (Windows style) line ending.

You should use this command to do that:

```
cat temp | tr '\r' | sed -e 's/$/,dfd0/' > output_file
```